# Why I can't risize Windows partition?

Tags: partitioning, windows, gparted, ntfs

I got free space in my hard disk, why I cant resize a windows partition?

I need to make free space next to the partition of Windows.

I'm in a live usb.

[image]

Comment: Well, you don't have contigous space for the partition to grow. You would have to move the linux partition to the right, and then resize... but moving partitions is a dangerous operation, you may corrupt your system.

Comment: IMO your best bet is to (always) backup your data, delete the linux partition, create a new partition using the unallocated space with space to the left for the windows partition to grow, then reinstall linux.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, you can shrink Windows partition from Windows OS.